# r raster read .vrt in a zip file

Tags: r, raster, rgdal, geotiff

I have a large zip file with a bunch of geotiff files in it and a .vrt file with the needed info for each. Rather than unzip all the files, I'd like to work directly with the zip file.

This command, with the .vrt and some of the geotiff files works, in the sense that temp raster is created as a rasterLayer but since not all the geotiff files are unzipped, plot(rasterLayer) fails with a missing data error.

```
tempraster <- raster("data-raw/CoastalDEMv1.1/tiles.vrt")
```

This command fails, presumably because I has specified the path incorrectly

```
tempraster <- raster("data-raw/Global_90.zip/CoastalDEMv1.1/tiles.vrt")
```

The error message is

> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",: 
>         Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)

Presumably, this means raster thinks the zip part of the path is just another folder. I need it to look inside the zip.

I'm running on a Mac, OS is Catalina.

Comment: What's the error message on the second fail? The one where you try and access the vrt through the zip file in the path? What operating system?

Comment: I added this information to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some text from [gdal.org](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html)

> To point to a file inside a zip file, the filename must be of the form
>   /vsizip/path/to/the/file.zip/path/inside/the/zip/file, where
>   path/to/the/file.zip is relative or absolute and
>   path/inside/the/zip/file is the relative path to the file inside the
>   archive.

So for my dataset I use

```
link <- "/vsizip/data-raw/Global_90.zip/CoastalDEMv1.1/tiles.vrt"
test <- raster(link)
```

test has the following characteristics

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 139316, 432360, 60234665760  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0008326395, 0.0008326395  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -56, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /vsizip/data-raw/Global_90.zip/CoastalDEMv1.1/tiles.vrt 
names      : tiles
```

As I work with this and learn more, I'll update the answer.

Comment: It's not working for me on R 4.1.1. It gives "Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)"